# Do redundant ndb.Model.put_async() calls end up being sent only once to the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a NDB model that exposes a few instance methods to manipulate its state. In some request handlers, I need to call a few of these instance methods. In order to prevent calling `put()` more than once on the same entity, the pattern I've used so far is similar to this:

```py
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    prop_a = ndb.StringProperty()
    prop_b = ndb.StringProperty()
    prop_c = ndb.StringProperty()

    def some_method_1(self):
        self.prop_a = "The result of some computation"
        return True

    def some_method_2(self):
        if some_condition:
            self.prop_b = "Some new value"
            return True
        return False

    def some_method_3(self):
        if some_condition:
            self.prop_b = "Some new value"
            return True
        if some_other_condition:
            self.prop_b = "Some new value"
            self.prop_c = "Some new value"
            return True
        return False

def manipulate_foo(f):
    updated = False
    updated = f.some_method_1() or updated
    updated = f.some_method_2() or updated
    updated = f.some_method_3() or updated
    if updated:
        f.put()
```

Basically, each method that can potentially update the entity returns a bool to indicate if the entity has been updated and therefore needs to be saved. When calling these methods in sequence, I make sure to call `put()` if any of the methods returned `True`.

However, this pattern can be complex to implement in situations where other subroutines are involved. In that case, I need to make the *updated* boolean value returned from subroutines bubble up to the top-level methods.

I am now in the process of optimizing a lot of my request handlers, trying to limit as much as possibles the waterfalls reported by AppStat, using as much async APIs as I can and converting a lot of methods to tasklets.

This effort lead me to read the [NDB Async documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async), which mentions that NDB implements an *autobatcher* which combines multiple requests in a single RPC call to the datastore. I understand that this applies to requests involving different keys, but does it also apply to redundant calls to the same entity?

In other words, my question is: could the above code pattern be replaced by this one?

```py
class FooAsync(ndb.Model):
    prop_a = ndb.StringProperty()
    prop_b = ndb.StringProperty()
    prop_c = ndb.StringProperty()

    @ndb.tasklet
    def some_method_1(self):
        self.prop_a = "The result of some computation"
        yield self.put_async()

    @ndb.tasklet
    def some_method_2(self):
        if some_condition:
            self.prop_b = "Some new value"
            yield self.put_async()

    @ndb.tasklet
    def some_method_3(self):
        if some_condition:
            self.prop_b = "Some new value"
            yield self.put_async()
        elif some_other_condition:
            self.prop_b = "Some new value"
            self.prop_c = "Some new value"
            yield self.put_async()

@ndb.tasklet
def manipulate_foo(f):
    yield f.some_method_1()
    yield f.some_method_2()
    yield f.some_method_3()
```

Would all calls to `put_async()` be combined into a single `put` call on the entity? If yes, are there any caveats to using this approach vs sticking to manually checking for an *updated* return value and calling `put` once at the end of the call sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I bit the bullet and tested these 3 scenarios in a test GAE application with AppStat enabled to look at what RPC calls were being made:

```py
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    prop_a = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    prop_b = ndb.StringProperty()
    prop_c = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class ThreePutsHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        foo = Foo.get_or_insert('singleton')
        foo.prop_a = datetime.utcnow()
        foo.put()
        foo.prop_b = str(foo.prop_a)
        foo.put()
        foo.prop_c = foo.prop_a.microsecond
        foo.put()

class ThreePutsAsyncHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.toplevel
    def post(self):
        foo = Foo.get_or_insert('singleton')
        foo.prop_a = datetime.utcnow()
        foo.put_async()
        foo.prop_b = str(foo.prop_a)
        foo.put_async()
        foo.prop_c = foo.prop_a.microsecond
        foo.put_async()

class ThreePutsTaskletHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @ndb.tasklet
    def update_a(self, foo):
        foo.prop_a = datetime.utcnow()
        yield foo.put_async()

    @ndb.tasklet
    def update_b(self, foo):
        foo.prop_b = str(foo.prop_a)
        yield foo.put_async()

    @ndb.tasklet
    def update_c(self, foo):
        foo.prop_c = foo.prop_a.microsecond
        yield foo.put_async()

    @ndb.toplevel
    def post(self):
        foo = Foo.get_or_insert('singleton')
        self.update_a(foo)
        self.update_b(foo)
        self.update_c(foo)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/ndb-batching/3-puts', ThreePutsHandler),
    ('/ndb-batching/3-puts-async', ThreePutsAsyncHandler),
    ('/ndb-batching/3-puts-tasklet', ThreePutsTaskletHandler),
], debug=True)
```

The first one, `ThreePutsHandler`, obviously ends up calling `Put` 3 times.

[image: ThreePutsHandler AppStat trace]

However, the 2 other tests that are calling `put_async()` end up with a single call to `Put`:

[image: ThreePutsAsyncHandler AppStat trace]
[image: ThreePutsTaskletHandler AppStat trace]

So the answer to my question is: yes, redundant ndb.Model.put_async() calls are being batched by NDB's *autobatching* feature and end up as a single `datastore_v3.Put` call. And it does not matter if those `put_async()` calls are made within a tasklet or not.

A note about the number of datastore write ops being observed in the test results: as Shay pointed out in the comments, there are 4 writes per modified indexed property value plus 1 write for the entity. So in the first test (3 sequential `put`), we observe (4+1) * 3 = 15 write ops. In the 2 other tests (async), we observe (4*3) + 1 = 13 write ops.

So the bottom line is that having NDB batch multiple `put_async` calls for the same entity saves us a lot of latency by having a single call to the datastore, and saves us a few write ops by writing the entity only once.

Comment: Every day you (me) learn something new a about AppEngine, I didn't know about batching (and couldn't find it in the docs) until I found a issue report about it that [shed some light](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=47) on the feature. BTW it does save a lot, latency and writing operation cost wise, it is just that every indexed attribute modified cost you 4 writes (plus one for the put) so your number make sense.

Comment: Glad I could open the door to new knowledge! About the 4 writes per attribute: I don't quite understand. My understanding of how datastore writes are performed (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write) is that there are 2 indexes per attribute (asc and desc), but I am obviously not getting this right... Could you shed some light?

Comment: This sounds about right. AFAICR there's some code to collapse multiple get_async() calls for the same key, but not for put_async(). Check ndb/context.py for get_once(). Note it is called by various get() methods but not by put().

Comment: If you look at the [billing page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs) you see the each indexed attribute (by default most of the attribute are indexed unless indexed=False specified on the entity) cost "1 write + 4 writes per modified indexed property value + 2 writes per modified composite index value". so in your first case the cost are (4+1)+(4+1)+(4+1) and in the 2nd and 3rd its 3*4 + 1.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum, my test seem to indicate that the multiple calls to `put_async` are indeed batched (collapsed?). Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ShayErlichmen! I have updated my answer to reflect this information.

Comment: @PascalBourque: they are batched, but not collapsed. Batched means a single RPC with two requests. Collapsed would mean that the RPC contains only a single request. That's what happens for get_async().

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating the object itself, and checking before returning response. Like the _p_changed attribute in Zope. Another alternative could be a request/threadlocal registry of modified objects that needs to be written before returning. For an example of threadlocal in GAE, check google/appengine/runtime/request_environment.py

Comment: I like your sugestion of annotating the object to know if it needs to be saved!